# Using the Union function in SQL to reverse columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL code to produce the following table of data:

```
    Select
    max([Player_Team]) as 'Team', 
    case when max([Player_Team]) = max([match_home_team]) then max([match_away_team])
 else max([match_home_team]) end as 'Opposition',  
    sum([Shots]),    
    sum([Shots on Target]),    
    sum([Goals]),    
    max([Time]),     
    max([Day])
    From [StatsTable]
    Group By [Team]
    
    Team       Opposition    Shots   Shots on Target   Goals    Time     Day
    Brazil      England         6           3            1       1200    Saturday
    England      Brazil         3            1           0       1200    Saturday
```

I am hoping to transform data to create a table that looks like:

```
    Team       Opposition    Shots    Shots on Target   Goals    Time     Day       O.Shots   O.SOT    O.Opp Goals
    Brazil      England         6           3            1       1200    Saturday      3       1          0
    England      Brazil         3            1           0       1200    Saturday      6       3          1
```

What would be the best way to achieve this? Something like creating two tables and then a `Union` join?

Comment: It makes no sense to be grouping on `Team`, and also selecting `MAX(Team)`

Comment: I have multiple rows (of different players) that play for the same `Team` if that makes sense

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: MS SQL Server MS

Comment: It still makes no sense. When you use `Group By [Team]`, you are telling the engine to create one row per team - applying the max function to the same column makes no logical sense. You are fortunate that no error is thrown if that is the case. Do you have sample data rows for Brazil where Opposition is NOT England?  I suspect your sample test data is over-simplified.

Comment: yes i have multiple games and rows so probably not the best sample data

Comment: @SOK . . . Sample data would really help other people visualize your problem better.

Comment: What does `max(Team)` mean anyway? What are you maxing by, it's just a piece of text?

Comment: I thought i needed to do this just to pick one of the team names. But maybe i dont need it at all? Sorry, still very much learning!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use self join to achieve what are you looking for.

**Schema:**

> ```
> create table StatsTable(player_Team varchar(50),match_home_team varchar(50),match_away_team varchar(50),   Shots int,Shots_on_Target int,Goals int ,   Time int,     Day varchar(50));
> insert into StatsTable values('Brazil','Brazil','England',6, 3, 1, 1200, 'Saturday');
> insert into StatsTable values('England','England','Brazil',3 ,1 ,0 ,1200 , 'Saturday');
> ```

**Query:**

> ```
> with cte as 
> (
> Select
> max(t.[player_Team]) team, 
> (case when max(t.[Player_Team]) = max(t.[match_home_team]) then max(t.[match_away_team])
>  else max(t.[match_home_team]) end) opposition,  
> sum(t.[Shots])shots,    
> sum(t.[Shots_on_Target])Shots_on_Target,    
> sum(t.[Goals])goals,    
> max(t.[Time])time,     
> max(t.[Day])day
>
> From [StatsTable] t 
> Group By t.[player_Team] 
> )
> Select
> t.team, 
> t.opposition opposition,  
> t.Shots,    
> t.Shots_on_Target,    
> t.Goals,    
> t.[Time],     
> t.[Day],
> o.[Shots] oppo_shots,    
> o.[Shots_on_Target] Oppo_Shots_on_Target,    
> o.[Goals] opp_Goals    
>
> From cte t inner join cte o on t.opposition=o.team
> ```

**Output:**

> | team | opposition | Shots | Shots_on_Target | Goals | Time | Day | oppo_shots | Oppo_Shots_on_Target | opp_Goals |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Brazil | England | 6 | 3 | 1 | 1200 | Saturday | 3 | 1 | 0 |
> | England | Brazil | 3 | 1 | 0 | 1200 | Saturday | 6 | 3 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=208050d6b330e6adbbab5653b2397cbc)*

Comment: thanks! i forgot to add, i have a `case` column in my query that creates the `opposition' column. Im getting a error when trying to join on that `case` query. This solution works otherwise!

Comment: Will you please clarify further more so that I can try to help you.

Comment: I have updated OP. Sorry for over simplifying!

Comment: No problem. I will update my answer shortly.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check. It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure there is a job for self-join

```
Select max(st1.Team), 
      max(st1.Opposition),  
      sum(st1.Shots),    
      sum(st1.Shots on Target),    
      sum(st1.Goals),    
      max(st1.Time),     
      max(st1.Day),
      max(st2.Team), 
      max(st2.Opposition),  
      sum(st2.Shots),    
      sum(st2.Shots on Target),    
      sum(st2.Goals)
 From StatsTable st1
 join StatsTable st2
   on st2.Team = st1.Opposition
Group By [Team]
```

Would it help?

PS. Not sure about syntax